# Adding specific range for y axis to plot

Tags: ggplot2, boxplot

I cannot work out how to apply a specific y axis range to my violin plot

current code is :

```
library(ggplot2)

X21$`gggnnn`<-as.factor(X21$`gggnnn`)
X21$`RTtype`<-as.factor(X21$`RTtype`)

bp<-ggplot(data=X21,aes(x=RTtype,y=RT,group=RTtype))+
  geom_violin(aes(colour=RTtype),outlier.alpha = 1)+
  facet_grid(.~gggnnn) +
  labs(x="AM or PM", y='Reaction time /ms')+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1,colour="black",alpha=1,outlier.shape=4)+
  ggtitle("AM and PM Reaction Time Distributions among Gamers and Non-gamers")+
  geom_jitter(data=X21,aes(x=RTtype,y=RT,group=RTtype, colour=RTtype,shape=gggnnn))+
bp
```

this gives the plot as shown:
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aggm.png

I then tried to set y axis limits with adding a '+ylim(150,900)' , however this just truncated my data:
[2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDiRs.png

I now see that this is a limit on the range of the data, not the values on the axis (i am looking for the y axis to go from 150  to 900, also i do not know how to change the y axis grid spacing, as it is currently in intervals of 250, which is harder to interperit, i would like to set this to 100.

I attempted to do this with '+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(150,900, by = 100))', However it had no effect on the plot

Any help would be much appreciated

datasheet format:
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXKXF.png

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce and show you your desired output.

Comment: i have managed to fix grid spacing, but I still cant define the range of the y axis.

Comment: here is the dput output:

Comment: function (x, file = "", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", 
    "niceNames", "showAttributes")) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (nzchar(file)) {
            file <- file(file, "wt")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else file <- stdout()
    .Internal(dput(x, file, .deparseOpts(control)))
}
<bytecode: 0x7f8d54cee520>
<environment: namespace:base>

Comment: I have added a picture of my datasheet also

Comment: all fixed now, added these lines:

Comment: coord_cartesian(ylim = c(100,900))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(100, 900, by = 200))

Answer (score 1):

in order to set y coordinate limits use

coord_cartesian(ylim = c(100,900))

generalised this is:

coordinates_cartesian(xlim = c(lower limit,upper limit), ylim( c =(lower,upper)

in order to set spacing use

scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(100, 900, by = 200))

Comment: `coordinates_cartesian` isn't a function